# Displaying the calculated age(in years) based on the entered 'Date of Birth' from the datePicker

Tags: javascript, php, html

I want to get the value of the entered date from the datePicker in the current age field using PHP or Javascript in a PHP file.

```
    if ($key == 'currentage') {
                    $group[] = $this->form->createElement("text", $field, null, null);
                    $this->fieldNotRequired($field);
                } elseif ($key == 'dob') {
                    $group[] = $this->form->createElement("date", $field, null);
                    $this->fieldNotRequired($field);
```

Comment: PHP runs on the server, so it can't *get* the value of anything, you must *send* it (if you need to do the calculation in PHP) - of course, it depends why you want the result - javascript can handle this level of calculation

Comment: Tag html, mysql and xml for what?

Comment: instead of inserting the age in years manually I want to display it automaticly when I choose the date from the datepicker. Which format is better to use in this case? Is XML would work, or Javascript?

Comment: XML is a data storage format, JavaScript is a programming language. If you want to persist this data for later use, then you will need both - a technique & place to store the data, and a programming language to do your calculation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you can do it using HTML and JavaScript. You would want to style with CSS vs the `<br />` tags. Hope this helps

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Age Checker</title>
</head>
<body>
    <label for="start"><strong>Birthday:</strong></label>
 <br />
    <input type="date" id="birthday" name="trip-start"
           value="1980-04-27"
           min="1900-01-01" max="2022-12-01" onchange="CheckDate()">
 <br />
 <br />

    <textarea id="results">
    </textarea>
</body>

<script>
    function CheckDate() {
        var birthday = document.getElementById('birthday');
        var birthdayYear = new Date(birthday.value).getFullYear();
        var birthdayMonth = new Date(birthday.value).getMonth();
        var currentYear= new Date().getFullYear();
        var currentMonth= new Date().getMonth();
        var results = document.getElementById('results');

        if (currentMonth < birthdayMonth) {
            results.value = "Current Age: " + (currentYear - birthdayYear -1);
        } else {
            results.value = "Current Age: " + (currentYear - birthdayYear);
        }
    }
    
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Can we create the same function under php.class.inc?

Comment: So if you want to do the logic in PHP, you would have to use ajax to push from the front-end HTML to the backend PHP and then push the results back to the front-end. You can not make dynamic changes to the page via PHP alone you would have to use JavaScript to push it back and forth and do all the updates. You can make the date picker a form that submits and then do the logic and refresh the page with the results, but that is the old and bad way to do things. Any reason that you want to do it in PHP?